# How does SendGrid notify (delivered-open-click) events when multiple email recipients are specified

Tags: email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

When you send an email through sendgrid, and the recipient opens the email, SendGrid will notify my server about that using webhooks (open) event.
https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event

But what happens if I specify multiple recipients for the same email with personalizations, do I get the same (open) event every time one of the recipients opens that email? If so how can my server figure which recipient?

What about the (delivered) event? Same questions.

Comment: We have the same issue in our app, and it seems that the first to open it wins. But I would love to know a knowledgeable answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The best way I found to achieve this is to send custom_args with the email, you can add `custom_args` to each individual personalisation object. Parameters set in `custom_args` are also sent along in the event webhook.

I wrote [a post about how to use `custom_args` to track email statuses](https://www.twilio.com/blog/track-email-status-ruby-on-rails-sendgrid). The post uses Ruby on Rails as the framework, but covers using `custom_args` and reading them back in the event webhook to update the email in your own database.

Comment: ```custom_args``` are specified per email, not per recipient, don't they? So they can help telling emails apart in the webhook handler, but they won't help telling multiple recipients of a single email apart

Comment: You can add custom_arts to the request in general or to each object in the personalizations array. The latter allows you to set them on a per recipient basis.